# Problems with nested "IF" condition in Lua (Love2D)

Tags: if-statement, lua, love2d, nested-if

Whenever I hit space bar I get this error: "Attempt to call field "resume" a nil value."
The intention is to the hit space bar once to stop the audio, and hit it again to resume.

```
if(key == "space") then
    love.audio.pause()
    paused = true
end
if paused == true then
    if (key == "space") then
        love.audio.resume()
    end 
end
```

Things I tried:
Changing "==" to "=" and vice versa;
Using "and" to avoid the nested "if" statement.

Documentation (if needed): http://love2d-community.github.io/love-api/#audio_resume

Any help is appreciated, and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if key == "space" then
   if paused then
      love.audio.resume()
   else
      love.audio.pause()
   end
   paused = not paused
end
```

But `love.audio.resume` [was removed](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.audio.resume) in LÖVE 11.
Use `love.audio.play` instead.